# sed is failing when regex pattern is a group

Tags: regex, macos, sed, regexp-replace, bsd

My sed command works when I try to replace a single pattern.

```
sed -i '' 's/^\(feature\)/replacement/g' change.md
```

It doesn’t do anything when the regex is a group.

```
sed -i '' 's/^\(feature\|bug\|security\)/replacement/g' change.md
```

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong? I tried a number of variations, but none seem to work.

My file:

```
## Features
feature:foo
feature: baz
## Bugs
bug: bar
bug: KK
```

Comment: Use ERE `sed -Ei '' 's/^(feature|bug|security)/replacement/g' change.md`

Comment: lol. I tried that — without modifying but without removing ``\`` from my pattern

Comment: @HatLess I'd also change your message in your profile. You might unintentionally help a noobie to nuke their mac.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On [macos](/questions/tagged/macos) sed refers to [`re_format(7)` man page](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=re_format&apropos=0&sektion=7&manpath=FreeBSD+13.1-RELEASE+and+Ports&arch=default&format=html) to describe regular expressions. Without `-E`, sed uses "basic regular expressions". The re_format man page calls these "obsolete REs".

This sentence seems to answer the question:

> Obsolete (“basic”) regular expressions differ in several respects.  ‘|’ is an ordinary character and **there is no equivalent for its functionality**.

(emphasis mine)

It appears `sed -E 's/^(feature|bug|security)/replacement/g'` is your easiest option.

Or `perl -i -pe 's/^(feature|bug|security)/replacement/g' file`